# Searching through .rtf files in table grids

Tags: tables, search, files

[image]

question - this is a table, and the user is trying to search for keywords under the column 2. However, the column 2 has a list of .rtf files. Can they search for a keyword inside the .rtf? Any advice/references would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is definitely possible. Are you asking *how to implement* such a feature, or *how it should work* for the user?

Comment: Thanks, Max. How would it work for the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider how Google Chrome behaves, when search term is within collapsed item. User is searching for "password", and Chrome displays a tooltip for the Sync collapsed section, where the search term is.

Try it yourself with `chrome://settings` URL:

[image]

So, just provide some visual indicator to achieve your goal.

Comment: @karthikrajendran, glad it helped you ;)